# Show tab bar after its hidden

Tags: iphone, controller, uitabbarcontroller

Is there any way to show a tab bar after it has been hidden?

Got a tabbar-nav structure. For one of the tabs, I need to hide the tab bar for its 2nd and 3rd level view. But at the same time I will need to show its 1st and 4th view.

The sample code from Elements isn't really applicable here I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found quite a good pragmatic solution to this problem - make the UITabBarController's view larger than it needs to be, so that the actual UITabBar is clipped by the screen.

Assuming that the tab bar view normally fills its superview, this sort of thing should work:

```
CGRect frame = self.tabBarController.view.superview.frame;
if (isHidden)
{
    CGFloat offset = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    frame.size.height += offset;
}
self.tabBarController.view.frame = frame;
```

The tab bar is still showing, but it's off the bottom of the screen, so appears to have been hidden.

It might have performance implications if it causes extra clipping, but so far, it seems to work.

Comment: thank you very much...it's reallyyy very much helpful for me...it's almost month searching end...

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a delegate method

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController2 shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Inside that you can check which index is selected and show the tab bar

```
if([[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:viewController])// it is first tab
{
      tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Hi mihirpmehta,

Not exactly the situation I am in. For my situation its a tabbar-nav structure. I hope to show the tab bar for the 1st and 4th level. But hide it for the 2nd and 3rd view.

The one you described is after clicking the tab bar items?
Wonder if I can do something like
delegate.tabbarcontroller.tabbar.hidden = false

delegate.viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO doesn't seem to return the tabbar back to view.

setting self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO at viewDidLoad is not working also

Comment: You're correct that hidesBottomBarWhenPushed is useless for this because as documented "the bottom bar remains hidden until the view controller is popped from the stack."

Answer (score 1):

The UIViewControllers that are pushed onto the navigation stack can do the something like the following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO; // Or YES as desired.
}
```

EDIT: Added additional code below to deal with the frame. Don't think I particular recommend this idea since it relies on the internal default view structure of a UITabBarController.

Define the following category on UITabBarController:

```
@interface UITabBarController (Extras)
- (void)showTabBar:(BOOL)show;
@end

@implementation UITabBarController (Extras)
- (void)showTabBar:(BOOL)show {
    UITabBar* tabBar = self.tabBar;
    if (show != tabBar.hidden)
        return;
    // This relies on the fact that the content view is the first subview
    // in a UITabBarController's normal view, and so is fragile in the face
    // of updates to UIKit.
    UIView* subview = [self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    CGRect frame = subview.frame;
    if (show) {
        frame.size.height -= tabBar.frame.size.height;
    } else {
        frame.size.height += tabBar.frame.size.height;
    }
    subview.frame = frame;
    tabBar.hidden = !show;
}
@end
```

Then, instead of using the tabBar.hidden change I originally suggested, do the following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tabBarController showTabBar:NO];
}
```

Obviously making sure that the implementation has included the category definition so that 'showTabBar' is known.

Comment: Tried the above... what happens is the tabbar gets hidden, but in place there's a white ugly empty strip where the tabbar is 'hidden'

Comment: Ah, yes, makes sense, and of course I didn't notice it because in the quick sample I tried my views already were white.

It seems as though you might actually have to affect the frame of the whatever view is in the main display area to take up the space left by the hidden tabBar.  That seems a bit of a hack to try to get it to cooperate though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but i think the below code would help to hide the tabbar on the viewcontroller you don't want it on and has the added benefit of automatically readding the tabbar when you come back from that view controller

```
UIViewController *hideTabbarViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];  
hideTabbarViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;  
[[self navigationController] hideTabbarViewController animated:YES];
```