# How to show toolbar, when the tabbar is hidden?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, toolbar, tabbar

Currently i am working in simple iphone application, Using tabbar to set five buttons then i select 3rd tab at the time tabbar is hidden, then i show the tool bar functionality in tabbar area, but the toolbar not shown, Is it possible to show toolbar when the tabbar is hidden time? please help me

Thanks in Advance

I tried this:

```
[self.tabbarController.tabbar setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982172/iphone-is-it-possible-to-hide-the-tabbar

Comment: Hi honey, try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544701/show-tab-bar-after-its-hidden by @imaginaryboy

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just set the hidden property of the toolbar to NO after `[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES]`;

Comment: Hi ravi, sorry to say this i tried your scenario, but its not help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable the tabbar for some pages but not others. What you could do is draw a toolbar over the tabbar.

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIToolbar * tb = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
tb.frame = CGRectMake(0, delegate.window.frame.size.height-44, 320, 44);
[delegate.window addSubview:tb];
```

Comment: Is there a toolbar being shown at all? Because I tried it in my app and it worked fine. Be sure to replace AppDelegate in the first line with the actual name of your app delegate.

Comment: My AppDelegate name is similar to this

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a tab bar in appdelegate.m file then only you can hide the toolbar.
or you can create a tool bar seperatly by this code

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 418, 320, 44);

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[toolbar release];
```