# Tab Bar Hides when Navigate

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have Four Tabs in My Project By Default First tab is selected which is Home Class When user navigate to any other class by selecting any tab i have to check that time that if user is loggedin in my application then he will navigate to class which he selected else he move to Login Screen.

```
 if(appDelegate.sessionId==0)
            {

                Login *objLogin=[[[Login alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil] autorelease];

                [self.navigationController pushViewController:objLogin animated:YES];

            }
            else 
            {
                CreatePoll *objLogin=[[[CreatePoll alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreatePoll" bundle:nil] autorelease];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:objLogin animated:YES];

            }
```

}

IF i navigate to Login Screen my tab bar gets Hidden and when i debug the code i came to know that Create Poll class is also get called in background i check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544701/show-tab-bar-after-its-hidden) to show tab bar which is hidden but cant get success. Please help me guys i m stucked with this problem from last 3 days.
Cant see my tabbar in Login Screen.Please Help

Comment: what you want?? you want to show the tabbar on loginscreen??

Comment: then see the bellow my code i edit it with No for hidden property

Answer (score 1):

just write this code in `viewWillAppear:` method to hide and show the `UITabBar`

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
```

**UPDATE:**

post these method in `AppDelegate.m` file and when you want to show and hide the Tabbar at that time create AppDelegate object and call this method

```
- (void) hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {

    int height = 480;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, height, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        } 
        else {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x,view.frame.origin.y, 320, 436)];
        }
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void) showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {

    int height = 480;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; 

    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews) {

        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, height, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];            
        } 
        else {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, height)];
        }
    }    

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: i think you set LoginViewController as a RootViewController in AppDelegate and then if user login sussess then you add tabbar from delegate i think you do it just check this and also post the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of AppDelegate mate..

Comment: I had set my Home View Controller in Root View Controller now if user select any of the tab at that time i have to chk user is login or not if not then move to login screen or move to selected screen

Comment: oh ok mate here you set LoginViewController as a parentView or RootViewController so here just present the Loginscreen insted of set as a parent or RootViewController.. just post code where you push or present LoginScreen

Comment: oh sorry mate.. but some method .. like in viewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear of Login clas somewhere u hide the bottombar or tabbar mate ??

Comment: (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

{
    appDelegate.tabBar.tabBar.hidden=NO;
}

Comment: you property synthesize UITabbarController in AppDelegate and if yes then what you give the name to this control..?? if give name tabBar the write this code mate.. [appDelegate.tabBar.tabBar setHidden:NO];

Comment: name of my tabbar controller in app delegate is tabbar

Comment: oh mate use [appDelegate.tabBar.tabBar setHidden:NO]; instead of appDelegate.tabBar.tabBar.hidden=NO; try its working mate

Comment: Your code is right but it will not work in my problem because when selecting tab my selected tab class and login class both class get called thats why tab bar becomes hide so now i want solution for this problem

Comment: @iSanjay post this code in Login class and see its working or not -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [appDelegate hideTabBar:appDelegate.tabBar];
}

Comment: Thanks for your lots of effort but cant see my tab bar in login screen